# How can I say this?

Tags: questions, usage

In this list of phrases, which sounds most natural or most natural and grammatically correct?
Did anybody saw in the news this week about the plane which was hijacked?
Has anybody seen in the news this week about the plane which was hijacked?
Has anybody seen in the news this week about the plane which have been hijacked?
Has anybody seen in this week's news about hijacked plane?
Has anyone seen the news this week about the matter hijacked plane?